# .read ERROR: cannot find symbol symbol: method read(bufferedreader,<null>) location: variable jtext1 of type jbutton

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
private void jtext1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                       

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();

    try
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        jtext1.read(br, null);
        br.close();
        jtext1.requestFocus();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

I tried to run this code in a JButton while creating a feature for an app & keep getting the error message:

cannot find symbol symbol: method read(bufferedreader,) location: variable jtext1 of type jbutton

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Read the content of a JTextField component? What is `jtext`, exactly?

Comment: I am trying to read a from any text file on my computer and jtext1 is the name of the button that I created in my JFrame that is supposed to allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're calling the `read()` method from a `JButton`, but buttons don't read files -- all they do is throw events when they're clicked so that you can run other code in response.

What you should be doing is calling `read()` on `br`, which is your `BufferedReader`. I'm not sure why you're trying to pass an instance of the BufferedReader to itself, but those aren't the parameters that [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) takes. Even if you called the method on the correct object, it would fail with a different error.

Typically, you'd use the [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) method, which, as its name suggests, reads an entire line of text, allowing you to handle a file line by line without having to tell your code how many bytes of data to process on each read.

You want to do something like this:

```
private void jtext1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    // Your FileChooser code should live in a separate method. If the user
    // selects the FileChooser from a menu, then create an event handler for
    // that menu item. 
    try
    {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

        String line = "";

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Do whatever you want with the line.
            // You can add it to an arraylist
            // or you can split() it into parts
            // or you can just print it to screen. Whatever.
        }
        br.close();
        // this line is probably unnecessary, but ultimately, not harmful
        jtext1.requestFocus();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out & let you know how it goes